How can I permanently disable additional mouse buttons that cause browser forward and back navigation without more software in Windows 10/11?
I have a bad habit of accidentally clicking either the forward or backward buttons by the thumb position on multiple mice I use (Office PC, gaming PC, etc).
Without installing any additional software, how can I disable these buttons? Clearly something is mapping these buttons to this function. Is it the browser, the operating system, god?
Is there some registry setting advanced hidden setting in Windows I can set to disable these?

You can’t. Your mouse is being picked up as mouse and as a keyboard (fundamentally that’s how those keys work), then those keys are mapped to existing keyboard functions, the only way I know how to disable those keys is to install the OEM software responsible for the mapping of those keys.

If it's a continual issue, modify your own mouse by removing the connector to undesired switches, or cutting wires. Check if you may bring it to the office; I can't imagine many IT departments objecting.

@Jeffrey Tillwick Please, add to your post the model and specs of your mice. And what Windows are you running on your computer? Win10 or Win11? Please, reedit the post tags too.
